# Antd steps component creating single instance instead of proper steps

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using antd steps component and fetching information of order processing from an API and the processes are stored in an array so I have to use map on the steps to populate the information however there is single step being created multiple times. I am looking to have line between them which is not happening because it is creating a single step 3 times.

I've attached the sandbox here to explain the problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-kare-lzxbv

Here is what actual steps look like which I am trying to do: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-kowalevski-c4ngz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
export default function App() {
  const [currentStep, setCurrentStep] = useState(1);
  const { Step } = Steps;

  const data = [
    { id: "100", name: "Step 1" },
    { id: "101", name: "Step 2" },
    { id: "102", name: "Step 3" }
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <Steps direction="vertical" current={currentStep}>
        {data.map((item, index) => (          
            <Step key={index} title={item.name} />
        ))}
      </Steps>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You are using the Steps tag in the loop, So it was not work.

Also create one function for next and previous steps for update the currentStep state.